PIC24 memory model problem error
I attempted to run a code to start understanding how PIC24 works but I run into a memory model problem. I don't understand what's his optimization issue since I have enough space to write it on, and when I attempt to switch the data model to small, the code still has errors I can't figure out a solution for.
Output file - data model DEFAULT:
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/customLEDS.X.production.hex
elf-cc1.exe: warning: Attempt to override license manager detected
main.c:51:6: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/tutua/MPLABXProjects/customLEDS.X'
main.c: In function 'main':"K:\MPLAB\bin\xc16-gcc.exe"   main.c  -o build/default/production/main.o  -c -mcpu=24EP128GP202  -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/main.o.d"      -mno-eds-warn  -g -omf=elf -DXPRJ_default=default      -O0 -msmart-io=1 -Wall -msfr-warn=off    -mdfp="K:/MPLAB/packs/Microchip/dsPIC33E-GM-GP-MC-GU-MU_DFP/1.5.258/xc16"

make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/tutua/MPLABXProjects/customLEDS.X'
main.c:71:9: warning: implicit declaration of function '__delay_ms'
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/tutua/MPLABXProjects/customLEDS.X'
"K:\MPLAB\bin\xc16-gcc.exe"   -o dist/default/production/customLEDS.X.production.elf  build/default/production/main.o      -mcpu=24EP128GP202        -omf=elf -DXPRJ_default=default      -Wl,--local-stack,,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1,,--script=p24EP128GP202.gld,--stack=16,--check-sections,--data-init,--pack-data,--handles,--isr,--no-gc-sections,--fill-upper=0,--stackguard=16,--no-force-link,--smart-io,-Map="dist/default/production/customLEDS.X.production.map",--report-mem,--memorysummary,dist/default/production/memoryfile.xml  -mdfp="K:/MPLAB/packs/Microchip/dsPIC33E-GM-GP-MC-GU-MU_DFP/1.5.258/xc16" 


xc16-ld 2.10 (B)

Default Code Model: Small
Default Data Model: Large
Default Scalar Model: Small

"program" Memory  [Origin = 0x200, Length = 0x155ec]

section                    address   length (PC units)   length (bytes) (dec)
-------                    -------   -----------------   --------------------
.text                        0x200               0x100           0x180  (384)
.text                        0x300                0x26            0x39  (57)

                 Total "program" memory used (bytes):          0x1b9  (441) <1%


"data" Memory  [Origin = 0x1000, Length = 0x4000]

section                    address      alignment gaps    total length  (dec)
-------                    -------      --------------    -------------------

                 Total "data" memory used (bytes):              0  (0) 


Dynamic Memory Usage

region                     address                      maximum length  (dec)
------                     -------                      ---------------------
heap                             0                                   0  (0)
elf-cc1.exe: warning: Attempt to override license manager detectedstack                       0x1000                              0x4000  (16384)


                 Maximum dynamic memory (bytes):         0x4000  (16384)

Info: Project is using a large data memory model when small data memory model is sufficient.

make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/tutua/MPLABXProjects/customLEDS.X'
build/default/production/main.o(.text+0x1c): In function `.LBB2':
: undefined reference to `___delay_ms'
build/default/production/main.o(.text+0x22): In function `.LBB2':
: undefined reference to `___delay_ms'

Info: Loading file: K:/MPLAB/packs/Microchip/dsPIC33E-GM-GP-MC-GU-MU_DFP/1.5.258/xc16/bin/../support/PIC24E/gld\\p24EP128GP202.gld
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:129: dist/default/production/customLEDS.X.production.hex] Error 255
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:85: .build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: .build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 362ms

Output file - data model SMALL :
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/customLEDS.X.production.hex
elf-cc1.exe: warning: Attempt to override license manager detected
main.c:51:6: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/tutua/MPLABXProjects/customLEDS.X'
main.c: In function 'main':
"K:\MPLAB\bin\xc16-gcc.exe"   main.c  -o build/default/production/main.o  -c -mcpu=24EP128GP202  -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/main.o.d"      -mno-eds-warn  -g -omf=elf -DXPRJ_default=default      -msmall-data -O0 -msmart-io=1 -Wall -msfr-warn=off    -mdfp="K:/MPLAB/packs/Microchip/dsPIC33E-GM-GP-MC-GU-MU_DFP/1.5.258/xc16"
main.c:71:9: warning: implicit declaration of function '__delay_ms'make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/tutua/MPLABXProjects/customLEDS.X'

elf-cc1.exe: warning: Attempt to override license manager detected
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/tutua/MPLABXProjects/customLEDS.X'
"K:\MPLAB\bin\xc16-gcc.exe"   -o dist/default/production/customLEDS.X.production.elf  build/default/production/main.o      -mcpu=24EP128GP202        -omf=elf -DXPRJ_default=default      -Wl,--local-stack,,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1,,--script=p24EP128GP202.gld,--stack=16,--check-sections,--data-init,--pack-data,--handles,--isr,--no-gc-sections,--fill-upper=0,--stackguard=16,--no-force-link,--smart-io,-Map="dist/default/production/customLEDS.X.production.map",--report-mem,--memorysummary,dist/default/production/memoryfile.xml  -mdfp="K:/MPLAB/packs/Microchip/dsPIC33E-GM-GP-MC-GU-MU_DFP/1.5.258/xc16" 
build/default/production/main.o(.text+0x1c): In function `.LBB2':


xc16-ld 2.10 (B)

Default Code Model: Small
: undefined reference to `___delay_ms'
Default Data Model: Large
Default Scalar Model: Small

"program" Memory  [Origin = 0x200, Length = 0x155ec]

section                    address   length (PC units)   length (bytes) (dec)
-------                    -------   -----------------   --------------------
.text                        0x200               0x100           0x180  (384)
build/default/production/main.o(.text+0x22): In function `.LBB2':.text                        0x300                0x26            0x39  (57)


                 Total "program" memory used (bytes):          0x1b9  (441) <1%
: undefined reference to `___delay_ms'



"data" Memory  [Origin = 0x1000, Length = 0x4000]

section                    address      alignment gaps    total length  (dec)
-------                    -------      --------------    -------------------

                 Total "data" memory used (bytes):              0  (0) 


Info: Loading file: K:/MPLAB/packs/Microchip/dsPIC33E-GM-GP-MC-GU-MU_DFP/1.5.258/xc16/bin/../support/PIC24E/gld\\p24EP128GP202.gld
Dynamic Memory Usage

region                     address                      maximum length  (dec)
------                     -------                      ---------------------
heap                             0                                   0  (0)
stack                       0x1000                              0x4000  (16384)

                 Maximum dynamic memory (bytes):         0x4000  (16384)

make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/tutua/MPLABXProjects/customLEDS.X'
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:129: dist/default/production/customLEDS.X.production.hex] Error 255
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:85: .build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: .build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 361ms)

The code:
#pragma config ICS = PGD1               // ICD Communication Channel Select bits (Communicate on PGEC1 and PGED1)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF             // JTAG Enable bit (JTAG is disabled)

// FPOR
#pragma config ALTI2C1 = OFF            // Alternate I2C1 pins (I2C1 mapped to SDA1/SCL1 pins)
#pragma config ALTI2C2 = OFF            // Alternate I2C2 pins (I2C2 mapped to SDA2/SCL2 pins)
#pragma config WDTWIN = WIN25           // Watchdog Window Select bits (WDT Window is 25% of WDT period)

// FWDT
#pragma config WDTPOST = PS32768        // Watchdog Timer Postscaler bits (1:32,768)
#pragma config WDTPRE = PR128           // Watchdog Timer Prescaler bit (1:128)
#pragma config PLLKEN = OFF              // PLL Lock Enable bit (Clock switch to PLL source will wait until the PLL lock signal is valid.)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Window Enable bit (Watchdog Timer in Non-Window mode)
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (Watchdog timer enabled/disabled by user software)

// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMD = NONE            // Primary Oscillator Mode Select bits (Primary Oscillator disabled)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF           // OSC2 Pin Function bit (OSC2 is clock output)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF            // Peripheral pin select configuration (Allow multiple reconfigurations)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD           // Clock Switching Mode bits (Both Clock switching and Fail-safe Clock Monitor are disabled)

// FOSCSEL
#pragma config FNOSC = FRCDIVN          // Oscillator Source Selection (Internal Fast RC (FRC) Oscillator with postscaler)
#pragma config IESO = ON                // Two-speed Oscillator Start-up Enable bit (Start up device with FRC, then switch to user-selected oscillator source)

// FGS
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Segment Write-Protect bit (General Segment may be written)
#pragma config GCP = OFF                // General Segment Code-Protect bit (General Segment Code protect is Disabled)

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000
// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
/* #include <shortcuts.h> */

void main(void) 
{
    PORTA = 0;
    PORTB = 0;
    TRISA = 0;
    TRISB = 0;
    LATA = 0;
    LATB = 0;
    AD1CON1 = 0;
    AD1CON2 = 0;
    AD1CON3 = 0;
    /* AD1CON5 = 0; why? */
    AD1CSSL = 0;
    AD1CSSH = 0;
    /* float R1;
    float G1;
    float B1; */
    while(1)
    {
        PORTAbits.RA1 = 0;
        __delay_ms( 200);
        PORTAbits.RA1 = 1;
        __delay_ms (200);
    }
}


The error is:

undefined reference to `___delay_ms'

You should either include the library or source code which implements ___delay_ms.
The 'memory model' related message is only an info, and not necessarily an issue:

Info: Project is using a large data memory model when small data memory model is sufficient.


I removed the "__delay_ms" from the code, and did compile it.

I just ran into the "Invalid target device" "[ Pgm ] at 0x0, expected 0x00040200, got 0x00000000.", I suppose I have to create another question for this issue..?

Yes, that's an unrelated issue. This is a linker error; your next question has to do with programmer/debugger issues.
